# Access pointer value in Parse.com object with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to access the "objectId" field in "User" table, while running a query on a "Photos" table.

Here is the Parse.com query (simplified) run on "Photos" table:

```
func checkDbForNewPhotos() {
var query = PFQuery(className:"Photos")
query.whereKey("fbId", equalTo:"34343434343434")
query.includeKey("user.objectId"); // Is this what is needed to access user info ?

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {


        for object in objects {
            println(object) // See sample object below
            println(user.objectId) // Error here: user type doesn't have member objectId
}
```

println(object): Here is a sample object returned from the query. I'm trying to access 9wEGRWSnTk from the "user" field which is a pointer to another table.

```
<Photos: 0x7c091fd0, objectId: 6D0aHreHsC, localId: (null)> {
alerts = 0;
country1 = france;
country2 = "";
imageFile = "<PFFile: 0x7b7d9130>";
user = "<PFUser: 0x7b7d95f0, objectId: 9wEGRWSnTk>";
}
```

How should I format that in swift to access 9wEGRWSnTk ?

Comment: object.user.objectId?

Comment: 'String?' does not have a member named 'objectId' no matter how I force unwrap with !

Comment: try: `println(object.user)`

Comment: nil : how weird isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
println(object["user"].objectId)
```

if the column where you store your user named as "user".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You need to cast it to a PFUser and then access the information.

```
let pfObject:PFObject = object as PFObject
let userObject:PFUser = pfObject["user"] as PFUser
print("User \(userObject.objectId)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just say EqualTo and use the PFUser.currentuser() 
that way you load everything from that user only 
else try to explain why you need the objectId when querying

```
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
```